# Pointer is not saving when loop exits?

Tags: c++, loops, pointers

I have a struct which contains a self referential pointer:

```
struct Node {
  Node* parent;
  //also has some other stuff
}


for ( Node n : nodeList) {
  states = //returns function a vector of nodes
  for ( i : states ) {
    newNode.parent = &n;
    newNodeList.push_back(newNode);
  }
  //correct newNode.parent here
}
//incorrect newNode.parent here
```

My problem here is setting the node that `newNode.parent` should be pointing at.
After some searching, it looks like this is happening because `n` doesn't exist outside of the loop, so `&n` is not pointing to where it's supposed to.

How can I point `newNode.parent` to `&n`?

Comment: n is a local variable. There is only ever one, and it's address doesn't change. But you don't show what nodeList is or how its iterator works, so no way to definitely answer

Answer (score 1):

Your outer range-for loop is accessing `nodeList`'s elements **by value**, ie it is making a local copy of each one.  You are then assigning the address of a local variable to `newNode.parent`. That is why the pointer is invalid outside of the loop.

You need to access each node **by reference** instead, so that you take the address of the original node, not a copy of it:

```
for ( Node &n : nodeList)
```

Comment: Wow! Was it really that simple? I ended up changing everything to pass in pointers instead of objects. Maybe I'll go back and try this,too.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to post this here in case anyone finds it. It took me a while to realize that you need parentheses when accessing struct values via a pointer. `(*i).value1` not `*i.value1`.

Comment: You should be using `i->value1` instead.